# 403 Forbidden Error display instead of a customised Error 404 page

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

i'm having this issue with my server, i'm trying to do a Error 404 display, but whn i go to an invalid URL i get this message.. Please where could the problem coming from?

```
        The requested URL /church/ffff.php     was not found on this server.

Additionallt, a 403 Forbidden error was        encountered while trying to use an           ErrorDocument to handle the request
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh it's because the htaccess doesnt automaticly enabled on local host you need to do this:

1. click on wamp icon
2. apache->apache modules-> and enable rewrite_module

Answer (score 0):

Whats your .htaccess look like?

You can add a custom handler like this:

In .htaccess (the top of it is best)
ErrorDocument 404 404.php

Comment: My .htaccess looks like this..........         
ErrorDocument 404 /c:wamp/www/church/404.php

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the server dont have accses to the 404 file, to fix this you should put the file in the same folder as your htaccess and instead of writing a full path(/c:wamp/www/church/404.php) you should just write the file's name - 404.php

Comment: oh it's because the htaccess doesnt automaticly enabled on local host you need to do this

1. click on wamp icon
2.apache->apache modules->rewrite_module